# how to plot a google map like in the url

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

please take a look at [this](http://www.in-pa.org/?page_id=187)

I just want to create a google map like this. I know it's an easy job, but I have no experience with creating maps..
I want to add multiple address on google maps and also add the respective email, address, telephone details too.

so if someone can tell me ways do it..I want to add replica of that map to my weebly site..

any kind of help is really appreciated..

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

What have you tried so far?

Have a look at the [Google maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript) and try creating a simple map. It isn't diffcult. You can find a tutorial [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial). Read the documentation, write some code. If you still have some issues and questions come back and ask them.

And to be a bit more helpful, here is the example of displaying a map (from the Tutorial):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<style type="text/css">
  html { height: 100% }
  body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px }
  #map_canvas { height: 100% }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=set_to_true_or_false">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions);
  }

</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will just create a map using google maps api and add markers to the map.

Documentation:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker

Look at the sourcecode of this example, it should tell you what to do:

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-coordinates